# How to copy files filtered with grep

Tags: linux

I need find and copy files in /usr/share/man

Especialy need man7-8 and everything that have "et" in name.
I try this:

```
ls man7 man8 | grep "et"
```

This works perfectly.

Than i want that files copy with cp but i dont know how to format it properly

```
ls man7 man8 | grep "et" | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /home/marty/homework
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because `ls directory` just outputs the filenames, without the directory prefixes. So `cp` doesn't know what directory to copy the file from.

But there's need for `ls` or `grep`, just use a wildcard.

```
cp man7/*et* man8/*et* /home/marty/homework
```

Your code would also fail for any filenames containing whitespace, since `xargs` treats that as a delimiter by default.